# Вид черепицы. Как написать?

Tags: грамматика, дефис

> черепица(-)татарка

или

> черепица «татарка»

Стоит ли писать с дефисом? Или лучше раздельно?

Comment: Исправьте метки.

Answer (score 1):

Это название черепицы, т.е. производственного изделия, а такие названия пишут в кавычках: черепица "татарка".

О том, что это именно название,говорит запись:

> Во время очередной краеведческой экспедиции, в хуторе Весник,
> Анапского района мной был обнаружен старый сарай, крытый конусовидной,
> в виде перевернутого желоба, черепицей. В разговоре с жителями хутора
> было выяснено, что данный вид черепицы начали изготавливать пленные
> турки ещё в 80-е годы XIX века, а хуторяне дали ей название -
> «татарка».
> http://slavhistory.ru/article/read/Zametki-o-cherepichnom-proizvodstve-na-Kubani.html

Так что если это письменный стиль, то правильным будет написание в кавычках без дефиса, это же не указание на национальность. В бытовой ситуации, например, в частном объявлении на продажу, возможно и без кавычек как устоявшееся общепринятое название, как, например, наган, которое уже воспринимается не как название, а как отдельный вид оружия.